Dos formas: al enviar una, añadir datos de la primera
Tengo dos formas, una con varios checkboxes que dependiendo de ciertas circusntancias pueden ser poquitas o decenas, entonces uso un arreglo con el nombre iddocs, la forma tiene un id "forma", con php reviso cuales han sido seleccionadas:
<form method="post" id="forma">
   <input type="checkbox" name="iddocs[]" value="1">
   <input type="checkbox" name="iddocs[]" value="2">
   <input type="checkbox" name="iddocs[]" value="3">
etc etc

Hasta aquí todo muy bien.
Una segunda forma, la tengo en una ventana modal con id="formaNotificacion" (modal de bootstrap 5)
En esta segunda forma doy la opción al usuario de enviar la lista de documentos que seleccionó en la forma 1 junto con unos comentarios y otros campos.
La idea entonces es que si el usuario selecciona en la forma 2, que desea enviar la lista de documentos seleccionados en la forma 1 (por medio de checkboxes con name = iddocs), la lista de checkboxes seleccionados se peguen a la forma 2 y se envíen.
Este es el código que tengo ahora al envío de la forma 2 formaNotificacion
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#formaNotificacion").submit(function() {
    $("#formaNotificacion").append("#forma input[name='iddocs[]' ")
    return true;
  })
});

Trato de pegar -append- los datos de la forma 1 a la forma 2, pero no he podido, no sé si mi código es correcto o de que forma puedo hacerlo, sin usar AJAX que no es lo que busco.

Aquí una demo de tu código, donde detengo el envío para mostrar lo que pasa:


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#formaNotificacion").submit(function() {
    $("#formaNotificacion").append("#forma input[name='iddocs[]'")

    event.preventDefault(); //Esta línea es detiene el envío, es solo para fines demostrativos y se debe quitar

  })
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="forma">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iddocs[]" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iddocs[]" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iddocs[]" value="3">
</form>

<form id="formaNotificacion">
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>



Como se puede apreciar en el código anterior, lo que estas añadiendo al segundo formulario es el string "#forma input[name='iddocs[]' " y NO la lista de elementos.
Te falta envolver ese string en $(..) para que busque y retone aquella lista


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#formaNotificacion").submit(function() {
  
                              //    ↓ eso falta
    $("#formaNotificacion").append( $("#forma input[name='iddocs[]'"))

    event.preventDefault(); //Esta línea es detiene el envío, es solo para fines demostrativos y se debe quitar

  })
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="forma">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iddocs[]" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iddocs[]" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iddocs[]" value="3">
</form>

<form id="formaNotificacion">
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>



Además, como puedes notar, los checkbox se quitan del primer formulario y se agregan al segundo. Si tu quisieras mantenerlos siempre en el primer formulario (es decir copiarlos no moverlos), puedes utilizar clone()


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#formaNotificacion").submit(function() {
  
                                                                //     ↓ lo clonamos
    $("#formaNotificacion").append( $("#forma input[name='iddocs[]'").clone() )

    event.preventDefault(); //Esta línea es detiene el envío, es solo para fines demostrativos y se debe quitar

  })
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="forma">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iddocs[]" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iddocs[]" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="iddocs[]" value="3">
</form>

<form id="formaNotificacion">
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>




Buena respuesta, explicando la causa del problema y las posibles soluciones de manera didáctica

@PabloLozano Gracias por tus palabras, me motivan a seguir mejorando y aportando. Saludos

Efectivamente faltó indicar que se trataba de una función y no una cadena. Ya me jala perfecto. Tu explicación excelente. Muchas gracias.
